# Cannot open lmdb db file in Caffe2

Tags: pytorch, caffe2

I installed Caffe2 from source for Ubuntu.
I don't use Anaconda and my python is python2.

`which python` gives me

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I can import lmdb in python.
I can run tutorials from this [page](https://caffe2.ai/docs/tutorials)

My problem in testing one of the examples is "Can't open lmdb file".

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c9a97f268658> in <module>()
      1 # The parameter initialization network only needs to be run once.
      2 # Now all the parameter blobs are initialized in the workspace.
----> 3 workspace.RunNetOnce(train_model.param_init_net)
      4 
      5 # Creating an actual network as a C++ object in memory.

/home/pytorch/build/caffe2/python/workspace.py in RunNetOnce(net)
    199         C.Workspace.current._last_failed_op_net_position,
    200         GetNetName(net),
--> 201         StringifyProto(net),
    202     )
    203 

/home/pytorch/build/caffe2/python/workspace.py in CallWithExceptionIntercept(func, op_id_fetcher, net_name, *args, **kwargs)
    178 def CallWithExceptionIntercept(func, op_id_fetcher, net_name, *args, **kwargs):
    179     try:
--> 180         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except Exception:
    182         op_id = op_id_fetcher()

RuntimeError: [enforce fail at db.h:190] db_. Cannot open db: /home/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb of type lmdbError from operator: 
output: "dbreader_/home/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb" name: "" type: "CreateDB" arg { name: "db_type" s: "lmdb" } arg { name: "db" s: "/home/caffe2_notebooks/tutorial_data/mnist/mnist-train-nchw-lmdb" }
```

I have all files and have read access.

I compiled pytorch with `USE_LMDB=ON`.

I see the same issues but can't find how they solved the issues.
My laptop system is small with `Ubuntu 16.4, with Nvidia Cuda GeForce GT 750M`, so quite old model.

Then I found in one page. They solved the issue with changing LMDB_MAP_SIZE in lbdb.cc. So I changed to 4G, but still have error.

```
constexpr size_t LMDB_MAP_SIZE = 4294967296;//4gb 1099511627776;  // 1 TB
```

The problem is at this line

```
workspace.RunNetOnce(train_model.param_init_net)
```

How to solve the issue?